# CSharpCodeProvider seems to be stuck at .NET 2.0, how do I get new features?

Tags: c#

I have the following, fairly standard code as a wrapper around `CSharpCodeProvider`. This class works very well, and performs just fine, etc, etc. But, despite the fact that my application is built against .NET 3.5 and is referencing v3.5 assemblies when doing this compilation, I still don't get access to any of the extra nice C# 3.5 syntax like lambda's or auto-properties. Is there some way to get this working?

I was under the impression that this class just wrapped around `csc.exe`, an idea that would seem to be confirmed by my firewall (my application tries to access `csc.exe`). Perhaps I just need to set `options.CompilerOptions` to something?

```
protected virtual void Compile()
{
    Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider csProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();

    CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
    options.GenerateExecutable = false;
    options.GenerateInMemory = true;
    options.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

    foreach (string s in this.ReferencedAssemblies)
    {
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(s);
    }

    CompilerResults result;
    string source = this.CodeTemplate;

    // [snip] Do some manipulation to fill in the template with values.

    result = csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, source);

    this.HasErrors = result.Errors.HasErrors;
    this.Errors = new CompilerError[result.Errors.Count];
    result.Errors.CopyTo(Errors, 0);

    if (HasErrors && ThrowOnErrors)
        throw new InvalidProgramException("The code currently stored in the " + this.GetType() + " cannot be compiled.");
    else if (HasErrors)
        return;
    this.CompiledAssembly = result.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have references to `mscorlib`, `System.Core`, `System.Text` and one of my own assemblies at the moment.

Comment: 3.5 is built on the 2.0 Framework.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a compiler flag that you can pass into the constructor (in a dictionary):

```
Dictionary<string,string> options = new Dictionary<string,string>
{ 
    { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" }
};

var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```

That's what's worked for me, anyway...

Comment: +1: I wrote a simple wrapper for this with enum values for framework versions so that I can specify which parts of the app support which compiler.

Comment: Praise to google for finding this old answer.  Saved me a ton of time, as this could really be documented better in msdn.  +1

Answer (score 0):

In referenced assemblies, try adding a reference to System.Core. That should do it. A lot of 3.5 functionality is in there. If that doesn't do it, open build properties for your current project and check what other assemblies you may have to load.

Comment: See my edit, but would references really make a difference to compiler behaviour?

Comment: No, they wouldn't. You want C# 3.0 language features, not (necessarily)  the .NET framework 3.5 class library. One does not require the other.